# Join two excel tables to output a table

Tags: sql, excel, vlookup

We have two excel files , they have the common filed ( student ID ) , I would like to join the tables so that the output as below table ( after vlookup ) , would advise what can I do ? thanks

## Table 1

| student ID | Student Name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Peter |
| 002 | Tom |
| 003 | Mary |

## Table 2

| student | ID | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Form | 1 |
| 002 | Form | 2 |
| 003 | Form | 3 |

## After `vlookup()`

| student ID | Student Name | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Peter | Form 1 |
| 002 | Tom | Form 2 |
| 003 | Mary | Form 3 |

Comment: what do you want? a query?

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 0):

With ***Microsoft-365*** can use-

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTER($E$2:$F$4,$D$2:$D$4=H2))
```

[image]

Comment: sorry , the table of my question seems has confused and not clear , I will post it again .